# Chaining of Eclipse plugins - SVN, Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs

Tags: eclipse, svn, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

My requirement is to create an eclipse plugin which will combine SVN, Checkstyle, PMD and FIndbugs. 
Before checking in into SVN the plugin should check the delta code, the new part to be checked in with Checkstyle,PMD and Findbugs error. IF there is any error it will not allow the code to be checked in.
How should I approach to solve this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you can write your own plugin which uses/triggers those 4 plugins (which must have been installed in advance). But this requires deep knowledge of eclipse plugin development and those 4 eclipse plugins. There are lots of tutorials for ecplise plugin development:

- [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html)
- [plugin development tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)

However there is another (easier) possibility - you need three (free) things:

1. SVN Server (which I assume is already set up)
2. CI (Continuous integration) server like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)
3. [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) server with three plugins installed: findbugs, PMD, checkstyle

If you set this up the following would occur (depending how you configured it):

1. Somebody checks something in
2. The CI server automatically builds it
3. sonar does a code analysis and sends an email if a rule was violated
4. Sonar itsself also has an [eclipse plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse) which combines all the rules you configured in sonar. Thus before checking in everybody can run it...

Your approach is not impossible however requires lots of knowledge and coding. So maybe the 2nd approach may provide a quicker solution. Also you will benefit from the other advantages of CI and the powerful sonar server which can do a lot more (e.g. analyse your test coverage ...)

Comment: Good answer. In addition, there is also a ["build breaker" plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin) for Sonar that you can use to fail the build if certain thresholds of Sonar warnings are reached.